# Apache Reverse Proxy Rewrite Remote_User

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-headers, reverse-proxy

Running httpd 2.4.6 on CentOS 7 as a reverse proxy for Splunk with SSO.

This works with no proxying:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} "user" [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

The above does NOT work with proxying.
I would like to match an authenticated user via basic auth.
The X-Remote-User header is being passed to Splunk (SSO debug confirms this).

I have tried using several headers like HTTP_X_REMOTE_USER but still no joy. I don't know enough to see what's going on via ProxyPass etc. Have checked trace rewrite log and enabled forensic log but nothing. Seems the variable is not known in the proxy rewrite environment and the entire block is skipped.

Is my approach wrong? Can I do this another way?

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Of
ProxyPass /sh https://127.0.0.1:8000/sh
ProxyPassReverse /sh https://127.0.0.1:8000/sh
RewriteEngine On
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User %{REMOTE_USER}s
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} "user" [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean, however....

> I have tried using several headers like HTTP_X_REMOTE_USER

`HTTP_X_REMOTE_USER` isn't an HTTP request header. That looks like the corresponding index that PHP creates in the `$_SERVER` superglobal for an HTTP header of the form `X-Remote-User`.

To match an HTTP request header using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` you can do use the `%{HTTP:Http-Request-Header}` syntax. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Remote-User} "user" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

`^.*$` is the same as simply `^`. No need for the `L` flag when using `F` (it is implied).

Comment: It sounds like he is looking for a header that passes along the remote user in a similar manner to how the IP is passed by the `X-Forwarded-For` header when behind a proxy.

Comment: I said I have "tried" other headers and that it _does_ work with REMOTE_USER _without_ proxying. Something breaks with rewrite and proxying.

Comment: Thank you, I'll clean up the RewriteRule in the meantime.